# Learning Go: How to use http.HandlerFunc?

Tags: function, go, handler

## Trying To Learn Go

### My Test Project

I am building a simple API to communicate with a light SQL database.
I created this function, that gets all hosts from the DB table.
As I understand, my function should take a pointer to the DB and return me http.HandlerFunc.

```golang
func (h HostController) GetAllHosts(db *sql.DB) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        var host entities.Host
        var hosts []entities.Host
        var errorMessage entities.Error
        rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM hosts WHERE hosts = ?", host)
        if err != nil {
            errorMessage.Message = "Error: Get all hosts"
            utils.SendError(w, http.StatusInternalServerError, errorMessage)
            return
        }
        defer rows.Close()
        for rows.Next() {
            err := rows.Scan(&host.ID, &host.Uuid, &host.Name, &host.IPAddress)
            if err != nil {
                errorMessage.Message = "Error: (Get all hosts) Can't scan rows"
                utils.SendError(w, http.StatusInternalServerError, errorMessage)
                return
            }
            hosts = append(hosts, host)
        }
        ////If hosts slice is empty -> no data in database
        if len(hosts) == 0 {
            errorMessage.Message = "No found hosts in database"
            utils.SendError(w, http.StatusInternalServerError, errorMessage)
            return
        }
        //Convert containers content to JSON representation
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        utils.SendSuccess(w, hosts)
    }
}
```

Now, Until here everything should be good, but I don't know how to implement this on main.go
build layout:

```
.
├── controllers
│       └── hostcontroller.go
│       
└── main.go
```

and this is how I am trying to implement it on the main.go

```golang
package main

import (
    "examProg/config"
    "examProg/controllers"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
)

func main() {
    db := config.GetDB() //Establishing connection to DBase
    {

        router := mux.NewRouter()

        router.Handle("/host", controllers.HostController.GetAllHosts(db))

        fmt.Println("Server is running at port: 2030")
        log.Println("Server Running OK | Port: 2030")
        log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":2030", router))
    }

}
```

I don't understand how to implement the http.HandlerFunc

Comment: What problem / error are you having with the code you showed?

Comment: not enough arguments in call to controllers.HostController.GetAllHosts (*sql.DB) (controllers.HostController, *sql.DB)
@HymnsForDisco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `controllers.HostController.GetAllHosts` is a [method expression](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Method_expressions). The result of a method expression is a `function` that, in addition to the `method`'s argument's, takes an instance of the **receiver's type as its first argument**.

Hence the *"not enough arguments in call ..."* error.

To illustrate:

```golang
f := controllers.HostController.GetAllHosts
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(f))
// output: func(controllers.HostController, *sql.DB)
```

So, to make the code compile, you need to pass an instance of `controllers.HostController` to the call, i.e.

```golang
controllers.HostController.GetAllHosts(controllers.HostController{}, db)
```

As you can see, it ain't pretty. Method expressions have their use, I'm sure, but I haven't encountered them much. What I see most often instead, is the use of [method values](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Method_values).

```golang
h := controllers.HostController{}
router.Handle("/host", h.GetAllHosts(db))
```